# YUV 422 , YUV 420 ,YUV 444

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, yuv

I have for example 4*4 image. I want to extract the Y,U and V components separately.
How to do it if the image is YUV 422 ,YUV 420 and YUV444.
I am interested in knowing the structure of array how Y,U and V are stored in 422,420 and 444,
so that it can be accessed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php) site gives you a pretty good overview over the different YUV formats. There's also a pixel-structure given.

For clarification: These numbers are for determination of [color component subsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling). For instance YUV 444 = 4:4:4 subsampling, meaning that every of the three components (Y, U and V) has the same sample rate. Whereas 4:2:2 states that U and V are only sampled with half the rate of Y. Or, in other words, 2 Bytes for Y and for U and V 1 Byte respectively, if the depth is 1 Byte. This implies that Y can have a higher dynamic range.

It is worth noting that JPEG standard defines horizontal and vertical sampling factors for each color component.  The human visual system has a [20:1 ratio of the luma sensors (rods)  to chroma sensors (cones)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoreceptor_cell).  For this reason, typically luminosity component is not subsampled, but the [JPEG standard](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf) does allow such content to be encoded.

Comment: So you use 2 Bytes for Y and 1 for U and V for pixel or you use 1 Byte of Y per pixel and shared U and V between 2 Bytes horizontally? It is not clear to me yet.

Comment: 4:4:4 would relate to 2 Bytes for each, Y, U and V. 4:2:2 would be 2 Bytes for Y, 1 Byte for U and 1 Byte for V.

Comment: The first site referred is down, here's a web archive version:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160303191501/https://fourcc.org/yuv.php

Answer (score 3):

it's a pretty old question, however I've just finish some work about decoding YUV and I would like to share some infos. There are 3 main aspects of the YUV schema:

1. If the source YUV buffer is a packed or planar buffer. Packed means
   that the YUV bits are grouped togheter, planar means the Y, U and V
   buffers are separated in 3 differents memory area.
2. YUV channel size; the single Y,U,V channel could be of 8-bit, 10-bit, 12-bit, etc
3. the sampling ratio; A:B:C. 4:2:2 means that you horizontally have 1 Y value for each pixels and one only U and V value shared between two neightboard pixels.

I've just worked on YUV 4:2:2 v210 decoding, following this [link](http://adec.altervista.org/blog/yuv-422-v210-10-bit-packed-decoder-in-glsl/) there is the GLSL source code to decode and the resources I referred to. Any advice is welcome, it's my first decoder.